# Optimal number of comparison to find min and max

Tags: algorithm

I know optimal number of comparison to for finding MINIMUM and MAXIMUM of n keys is

> 3n/2

but what if n is an integer power of 2 ? Then what would be number of comparison ?

Some more details:

For example, a graphics program may need to scale a set of (x,y)
data to fit onto a rectangular display screen or other graphical output device.To do so, the program must first determine the minimum and maximum value of each coordinate. At this point, it should be obvious how to determine both the minimum and the maximum of n elements using ‚theta(n) comparisons, which is asymptotically optimal: we simply find the minimum and maximum independently, using n -1 comparisons for each, for a total of 2n -2 comparisons.So in this case we can find both minimum and maximum in 3[n/2] comparison. But what if n is a power integer of 2 ? Then what would be the number of comparison to find MIN and MAX of n keys ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i added some details

Comment: Why do you believe that `n` being an integer power of two makes a difference? That is, why do you think `3n/2` doesn't apply here?

Comment: @MarkDickinson i am just confused whether the number of comparison would be logarithmic or does it stay the same. Because we compare pairs of elements from the input first with each other, and then we compare the smaller with the current minimum and the larger to the current maximum, at a cost of 3 comparisons for every 2 elements

Comment: How do you know that 3n/2 is the optimal number of comparisons to find the min and max of n numbers? On checking n=1, 2, 3, 4 it seems to be wrong. For n=1, 2, 3, 4 you need 0, 1, 3, 4 comparisons respectively, and 3n/2 is 1.5, 3, 4.5, 6.

Comment: @jon: Trivially, it cannot be much better for N=2^p. The trivial reason is that we can always lengthen a sequence by repeating its last element. This doesn't affect min and max. So if it would be an O(log N) operation for N=2^p, it would also be O(log N) for all other lengths.

Comment: actually the optimal number of comparison is `ceil(3n/2) - 2`. It also does not matter whether n is an integer of power of 2.

Comment: @PaulHankin i am following intro to algorithm book and i do see that book is referring to odd-even numbers. So if n is odd then it is 3n/2 comparison and if n is even then we perform 3n/2-2 comparison. So in either case it is total of 3n/2 comparison. I am Glad u brought this up.

Comment: @jon Are you sure the book doesn't say 3(n-1)/2 in the odd case?

Comment: @PaulHankin yes it says  3n/2 in odd case MIT book Intro to algorithms

Comment: That's odd.. (no pun intended). E.g. n = 3. you can compare: 1) a and b, assign bigger one to max, and smaller to min. 2) compare c to max, 3) compare c to min. That took 3 comparisons, instead of 3*3/2 comparisons.

Comment: It's either a typo in the book, or more likely @jon has failed to correctly transcribe the formula. Perhaps it says 3[n/2] where [] means round down.

Comment: @PaulHankin no mistake on my end sir. Please refer Page # 215 CLRS 3rd edition

Comment: @jon On the copy I'm looking at it says "Let us analyze the total number of comparisons. If n is odd, then we perform 3[n/2] comparisons" where [] are round down brackets -- which look like square brackets except the top horizontal line is missing, as described on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions